# How to display and plot a binary file in python?

Tags: python

I need to display and plot a binary file in python. I try by this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
path= "filename.bin"
dataArray= np.load(path)
test= dataArray.shape
print(test)
print (dataArray)
print (dataArray.shape)
plt.plot(dataArray.T)
plt.show()
```

But, it doesn't work. 
This is the error:

```
 "Failed to interpret file %s as a pickle" % repr(file))
IOError: Failed to interpret file 'filename.bin' as a pickle
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Do you get an error message or does your plot contain meaningless data? Could you describe what you should get?

Comment: @ma3oun Could you please see the edited question?

Comment: From the documentation of numpy.load, the problem comes from your binary file. Maybe it has been generated badly. Have you tried your script with a simple pickle file?

Comment: Did the file originate from python or is it a random .bin file exported from another program? Maybe share an example file with us.

Comment: It is exported from another program,